# Is it possible to make PNG hollow?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, png, transparency

I have a PNG image of a hand cutout overlay on top of google map, as shown here.

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11002845/handmap.png]

How do I make it such that I can click-drag the map when my mouse is over the hand cutout. Initially I thought that the hand cutout is hollow, but this was not the case. Any ideas or solutions to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply `pointer-events: none;` to PNG image. [Here is great tutorial from Tutsplus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/add-a-touch-of-realism-to-your-google-maps/)
- Google maps with png mask. NOTE: see [list of supported browsers for `pointer-events` property.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)